# How to correctly populate vertex array

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex, triangulation, vertex-array-object

I am confused with how to populate my vertex array for it to be correctly drawn. The OpenGL code that I am using is:

```
float vertices[size];
//Here I have a method to populate the array with my values from a 2D matrix

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID[0]); // Create our Vertex Array Object
glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]); // Bind our Vertex Array Object so we can use it

glGenBuffers(1, vboID); // Generate our Vertex Buffer Object
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]); // Bind our Vertex Buffer Object
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (size) * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Set the size and data of our VBO and set it to STATIC_DRAW

glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); // Set up our vertex attributes pointer
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Disable our Vertex Array Object
glBindVertexArray(0); // Disable our Vertex Buffer Object

glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]); // Bind our Vertex Array Object
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size/3); // Draw
glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind our Vertex Array Object
```

Hopefully the image makes this easier to understand. In image 'A' the 3x3 matrix on the left shows what I am currently getting when I draw triangles, the matrix on the right is what I am trying to achieve.

Currently when I create the array of vertices to draw from, I populate it in the order shown in image 'B'. I add values to the array as I work along a row, then step down a column and repeat. So for example:

```
vertexArray[0] = matrixElement[0].x  
vertexArray[1] = matrixElement[0].y  
vertexArray[2] = matrixElement[0].z  
vertexArray[3] = matrixElement[1].x  
vertexArray[4] = matrixElement[1].y  
vertexArray[5] = matrixElement[1].z
```

This order of input into the vertexArray gives results that can be seen in image 'C', where the wrong triangles are created.

My question is: what is the sensible way of populating a vertex array, in an order that is going to create triangles on a large matrix of vertices in a way that looks like the right hand diagram in image 'A'.

[image: Image of issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid any redundancy, and draw the whole mesh with a single draw call, one option is to use a combination of:

- `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` as the primitive type.
- Indexed drawing.
- Primitive restart (requires OpenGL 3.1 or later).

The primitive restart feature is needed because you can't easily represent this mesh with a single triangle strip. Using the numbering from your sketch, you can for example describe the topology with two triangle strips using these two index sequences:

```
0 3 1 4 2 5
3 6 4 7 5 8
```

Setting up and enabling primitive restart can be done with these calls:

```
glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xFFFF);
```

You can chose the index, but the common policy (and only option supported in OpenGL ES) is to use the largest possible value, which is 0xFFFF if you use `GLushort` as the type of the indices.

Once primitive restart is enabled, the "special" index will then start a new triangle strip. So the two triangle strips above can now be given by a single index sequence:

```
0 3 1 4 2 5 0xFFFF 3 6 4 7 5 8
```

You should be able to find plenty of examples that show how to set up an index buffer (you can recognize them by their use of `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`), so I'll skip that part. The draw call is then:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 13, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

where 13 is the number of indices used.

There are alternatives to using primitive restart:

- Use repeated vertices. This was a common trick before primitive restart was widely available. I wouldn't recommend it anymore. Just for illustration, the index sequence in this case would be:

  ```
  0 3 1 4 2 5 5 3 3 6 4 7 5 8
  ```

  The two repeated indices will result in a degenerate (0 pixel) triangle that "connects" the two triangle strips.
- Use `glMultiDrawElements()` to draw multiple triangle strips with a single draw call.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `GL_TRIANGLES` and `glDrawArrays()` so you'll need to append 3 vertexes for each triangle you want:

```
// first vertex
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[0].x );
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[0].y );
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[0].z );

// second vertex
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[3].x );
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[3].y );
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[3].z );

// third vertex
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[1].x );
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[1].y );
vertexArray.push_back( matrixElement[1].z );
...
```

Comment: So massive duplication of data? Is there a way I can store the vertices once, but reference them multiple times?

Comment: @Calco: Sure, using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` & indexed vertex submission via `glDrawElements()`.

Comment: @Calco Yes there is such a way, and that way is `glDrawElements` and element array buffers (also called index buffers, or index buffer objects).

Answer (score 1):

For what you are looking for, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` would be a better choice than `GL_TRIANGLES`. For an example on how to arrange vertices, see [here](http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/opengl-3d-graphics/understanding-gl_triangle_strip)